# Trying to use remote variable in If-Condition within ScriptBlock using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-remoting

I am trying to use below code to remove the groups from Active Directory. I am maintaining an input file for the list of servers. the input file is in the local machine and trying to use the content of the file inside the ScriptBlock using ($Using:variablename) after taking a remote session.

I am getting the content[file content] of the variable inside the ScriptBlock which is defined outside the ScriptBlock. The issue is the if condition [**if($serverlist -ne $null)**] is satisfying even if the variable is empty. The code is entering into if block even if the variable $serverlist is null, instead it has to take else block.

Could you please help me on this.

```
$adserver = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter AD server details"
$adserver
$askcredential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "NetBiosUserName")
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($askcredential.UserName,$askcredential.Password)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "$adserver" -Credential $credential
#$command = (Get-ADForest).domains
$addomain = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the Domain"
$servers = Get-Content "D:\Bhargavi\Windows-Decommission\$addomain\servers.txt"

#Invoke-Command -ComputerName $adserver -Authentication Default -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
#$addomain = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the Domain"
#$servers = Get-Content "D:\Bhargavi\Windows-Decommission\$addomain\servers.txt"
#Param($domainname,$serverlist)
$serverlist = $Using:servers
$domainname = $Using:addomain 
Write-Host "the list is $serverlist"
Write-Host "the domain is $domainname"


if($serverlist -ne $null)
{
    Write-Host "Found the data in the input file. Proceeding to remove the groups."
    foreach ($server in $serverlist) 
    {
        write-host "Server Name is: $server"
        $mgserver = "MG-$server"
        $mggroup = Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like $mgserver }
        $mggroup
        if($mggroup -ne $null)
        {
            Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like $mgserver } #| Remove-ADGroup -Confirm:$False
            $mggroupconfirm = Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like $mgserver }
            if($mggroupconfirm -eq $null)
            {
                Write-Host "$mgserver is removed from $domainname"
                #Set-Content -Path "D:\Bhargavi\Windows-Decommission\$domainname\servers.txt" -Value (get-content -Path "D:\Bhargavi\Windows-Decommission\$domainname\servers.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "$server" -NotMatch)
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "$mgserver is not removed. Please try again."
            }
        }
        else{Write-Host "There is no group called $mgserver in $domainname domain "}
        
    }
}
else
{
    DO
    {
        $val = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to enter servername ? Enter yes or no"
        if($val -eq "yes")
           {
                $entermgserver = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the server name"
                $entermgserver
                $mgserver = "MG-$entermgserver"
                $mgserver
                $mggroup = Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like $mgserver }
                $mggroup
                if($mggroup -ne $null)
                {
                    #Write-Host "$mggroup is not null"
                    Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like $mgserver } #| Remove-ADGroup -Confirm:$False
                    $mggroupconfirm = Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like $mgserver }
                    if($mggroupconfirm -eq $null)
                    {
                        Write-Host "$mgserver  is removed"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Host "$mgserver is not removed. Please try again."
                    }

                }
                else{Write-Host "The is no group called $mgserver in $domainname domain"}
           }
    
    }until ($val -eq "no")

}

} ### End Script Block

Clear-Content "D:\Bhargavi\Windows-Decommission\$addomain\servers.txt"

Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

Comment: The use of null in a condition should always be on the left hand side.  Not sure this is your problem, but I suggest changing the line to `if($null -ne $serverlist)` and report back if the problem continues.

Comment: Thanks Darin! This worked. I have used -like operator instead of -ne, then it worked. Thanks for your response :)